# How to remove irrelevant records from cache when you know the sequence of the queries?

Tags: java, algorithm, caching

Let's imagine there's a middleware server that stores *N* records and returns them by some id. If the server doesn't have a record in cache, it asks for it from the database. The sequence of queries is known from the beginning. The goal is to figure out the least amount of requests to the DB.

Example: cache can store up to 5 records and there are 15 requests by id. Let them be:

```
3
1
4
1
5
9
2
6
5
3
5
8
7
9
3
```

So it stores 3, 1, 4, then gets 1 from cache, then stores 5 and 9, then removes 1 to record 2 as it is not used further, then 6 replaces 2 and so on... hope you've got the point.

I need to write a console Java app that implements only that algorithm but I have no idea how

I thought some cache algorithms like LRU or MRU could help but they work according to relevance of the cache items, not the request sequence items. Of course, I can just loop through the sequence every time and see if the id there or not but that's long as hell I guess cause there can be up to 100000 items...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You say: _"removes 1 to record 2 as it is not used further"_ - When you get this working, I'm sure lots of people will be interested to learn of an algorithm that predicts the future :-)  In the meantime: This site is not a discussion forum or programming tutorial site.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Bélády's optimal page replacement algorithm. This records the sequence and then replays it to make the best choice due to knowing which entry is next accessed the furthest into the future. A good implementation is O(n lg n) by organizing the accesses efficiently for the replay run.